# How to change "<?php ?>" into "{ }"

Tags: php

While working, i countered  a `Php` project, which  use `{something}` or `@something` ( Laravel)
instead of `<?php something; ?>`
How could php understand it???
Could someone tell me??

Comment: Use templating engine like `blade` which laravel uses or `twig` or `smarty`

Comment: to who did '-1' to me. Please ask yourself. Could you config our php parser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the [Blade template engine](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade) which is built into Laravel. There are other template engines such as [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

The way PHP can understand it is because the template engine parses the template special syntax (`{{something}}` etc), and transforms it to working PHP code.

Comment: i want to add into the php parse  like this  `{abc}` so that  i will just `{something}` in stead of `<?php echo something; ?>`

Comment: @Hanata Sure, if you make a parser which parses the code and transforms it into actual php code.